# In which cases put a process itself in an sleep ?

Tags: process, sleep, operations, usleep

I really would like to know about some cases that a process put itself in a sleep.

What would happen for example in following cases? Would the process put itself in a sleep? and why ?

- Multiply of big number of values
- Waiting for user input
- Reading of dates from central memory
- Closing an open date
- Showing an loaded website on the display

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not seeing the point of this question.  A process will put itself to sleep if there is a need.  Doubtful you would go to sleep waiting for input, though.